# NullPointerException in a constructor call

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, nullpointerexception

I'm writing an android application and i have a problem.
The app use a doubly concatenated list. An activity create a record and at the click of the button save call a method that pass the created record at the list's add method.
It work only first time, then it throw a NullPointerException calling the constructor of List Node.
The error occur only in android, on the pc it work well. 
Here is the code and the thrown exception.

```
public boolean add(Object data) {
    boolean control = false;
    try {
        if (isEmpty()) {
            ListNode newNode = new ListNode(data);
            setFirstNode(newNode);
            setCurrentNode(newNode);
            incrementNumberOfNodes();
            control = true;
        }
        else {
            ListNode newNode = new ListNode(data, currentNode.getNextNode(), currentNode);
            if (currentNode.getNextNode() != null) {
                currentNode.getNextNode().setPreviousNode(newNode);
            }
            currentNode.setNextNode(newNode);
            currentNode = newNode;
            incrementNumberOfNodes();
            control = true;
        }
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        System.err.println(e);
    }
    return control;
}


public void save(View v){
    String action = getIntent().getAction();
    if(action.compareTo(GlobalVariables.ACTION_NEW) == 0) {
        newRecord();
        System.out.println("Save finish with new Record");
    }
}

private void newRecord(){
    EditText title = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.title);
    EditText password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);

    int key = GlobalVariables.firstFreePosition();

    Record newRecord = new Record(key,title.getText().toString());
    newRecord.setPassword(password.getText().toString());
    System.out.printf("RECORD CREATO: %s\n", newRecord);

    // Aggiungo il record alla lista
    boolean control = GlobalVariables.recordsList.add(newRecord);
    System.out.println("New Record = " + control);
}
```

Here is the constructors:

```
protected ListNode(Object data, ListNode nextNode, ListNode previousNode){
    setData(data);
    setNextNode(nextNode);
    setPreviousNode(previousNode);
}
```

And here is the exception (list.java's 120th line is the call of list node constructon) :

```
09-09 21:27:39.711  19605-19605/cf.portaChiavi E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at cf.list.List.add(List.java:120)
        at cf.portaChiavi.NewRecord.newRecord(NewRecord.java:161)
        at cf.portaChiavi.NewRecord.save(NewRecord.java:90)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
```

Please help me. 
Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it

Comment: Please add the actual relevant code. [Check this page for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @JerryF I hope you are not extending the ListNode with Activity

Comment: @bcsb1001 i'm sure that the record i've passed to the add method is not null because i've already try to stamp before to pass to add.

Comment: @Marcelo which code do you want to see?